# How to get a date at 0h 0m 0s?

Tags: php

I want to get the date at 30 days ago :

```
$one_month_ago = date_create("now");
date_sub($one_month_ago, date_interval_create_from_date_string('30 days'));
```

I want `$one_month_ago` to have its hour part, minute part and seconds part to be all 0. How to do that ?

Comment: Pass `today` instead of `now`.

Comment: How to know the keyword to enter inside `date_create` ?

Comment: Here's a complete [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//on 2020-11-26 15:26
$midnight30daysAgo = date_create('-30 days 00:00:00');
var_dump($midnight30daysAgo);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-10-27 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

Subtract one month:

```
$one_month_ago = date_create('-1 month 00:00:00');
var_dump($one_month_ago);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-10-26 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

**Note: At the end of the month may lead to unexpected results due to an bug / inconsistency in PHP by a adding / subtracting months**